# I am trying to send a message to a specific channel using ID, but it outputs Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a suggest command that I want to send to a specific channel in my server.

```
if (!args) return message.channel.send("Please input a suggestion"); {
client.channels.get("563804889268879390").send({embed: {
color: 0x333333,
author: {
 name: "New suggestion!",
},
fields: [{
 name: "User",
 value: ${message.author.user}
},
{
 name: "Suggestion",
 value: args
},
]}})}
```

I've defined message as `client.on("message", async message => {`.
Even when I type the command without any arguments, it doesn't respond with the error message. All it outputs when I try to use it is `(node:17876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`. The arguments work fine on my other commands, so I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Could tell us please how you defined message?

Comment: I've changed my post to fit, thanks

Comment: At the end of the first line you have an opening bracket which doesn't really fit in. Why's that? Perhaps that's causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` most likely means that `client.channels.get("563804889268879390")` is undefined, meaning the ID of the Channel is wrong or the Bot is not in the Guild where the Channel is in.

Make sure that the ID is valid!

Comment: Thanks!  The channel had permissions, and I forgot I didn't allow the bots to send messages.